# Biblical reference in Francis Bacon's essay: Background and significance

Tags: allusions, the-bible, essays, francis-bacon

> The first creature of God, in the works of the days, was the light of the sense; the last was the light of reason; and his sabbath work, ever since, is the illumination of his Spirit. First, he breathed light upon the face of the matter, or chaos; then he breathed light into the face of man; and still he breatheth and inspireth light into the face of his chosen.

This belongs to Francis Bacon's essay *"Of Truth"* that I've come across lately. I guess this part of the essay has some connections to the Bible. As I'm not Christian I don't know exactly. Nevertheless I'm eager to know how Bacon has related his writing to the Bible here and what it implies. Truthfully speaking I don't get the message or meaning of *"light of sense"*, *"light of reason"* here and why the author used it in the essay; in what context?

Comment: Refer to the 7 days of creation : [Genesis](https://www.gotquestions.org/creation-days.html).

Comment: The word **sense** needs to be glossed here. The Elizabethan word could refer to the five senses. Genesis can provide background but there's an English question lurking in there.

Answer (score 2):

In this passage Bacon plays on various senses of the words “light” and “breath” to create a series of parallels between parts of the story of creation in [Genesis chapters 1–2](https://biblehub.com/niv/genesis/1.htm). I’ll gloss the whole passage.

> [Bacon] The first creature of God, in the works of the days, was the light of the sense.

Here we need the following senses of the words:

> **creature, *n.* 1.a.** A created thing or being; a product of creative action; a creation.
>
> **sense, *n.* 12.b.** The bodily senses considered as a single faculty in contrast to intellect, reason, will, etc.
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*.</sub>

The “days” are the seven days of creation, and the “works” the actions or creations of God, the first of which was light:

> And God said, “Let there be light,” and there was light.
>
> <sub>[Genesis 1:3](https://biblehub.com/genesis/1-3.htm). New International Version.</sub>

This is literal light, which can be seen and felt by human senses. In the next clause, Bacon contrasts this with another kind of light:

> [Bacon] the last was the light of reason

The last things to be created in Genesis chapter 1 were human beings, who are capable of “reason” (rational thought):

> So God created mankind in his own image, in the image of God he created them; male and female he created them.
>
> <sub>[Genesis 1:27](https://biblehub.com/genesis/1-27.htm). New International Version.</sub>

So Bacon uses “light” here in the metaphorical sense:

> **light, *n.* 7.a.** Mental illumination; enlightenment, knowledge, which may be possessed by a particular person or derived from a particular source; often in **the light of reason**.
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*.</sub>

“The light of reason” (*lumen rationalis*) was a set phrase in theological writings, for example in Aquinas, who distinguishes it from “the light of divine revelation”, for example:

> Unde nihil prohibet de eisdem rebus, de quibus philosophicae disciplinae tractant secundum quod sunt cognoscibilia lumine naturalis rationis, et aliam scientiam tractare secundum quod cognoscuntur lumine divinae revelationis
>
> Thus nothing prevents those things, which the methods of philosophy show are knowable by the light of natural reason, from being shown by another science to be known by the light of divine revelation.
>
> <sub>Thomas Aquinas (c. 1274). [*Summa Theologiae* I.1](https://la.wikisource.org/wiki/Summa_Theologiae/Prima_pars/Quaestio_I#Articulus_1). Wikisource.</sub>

Next Bacon further elaborates the theme of “light”:

> [Bacon] and his sabbath work, ever since, is the illumination of his Spirit

On the seventh day of creation, God rested ([Genesis 2:2](https://biblehub.com/genesis/2-2.htm)); and (in Bacon’s time) on Sundays people rested from work and went to church, where they received “illumination” in the sense:

> **illumination, *n.* 2.a.** Spiritual enlightenment; divine inspiration.
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*.</sub>

In the second sentence of the passage, Bacon repeats the ideas from the first sentence, but strengthens the parallels by adding “breath” and “face” in each case.

> [Bacon] First, he breathed light upon the face of the matter, or chaos;

This refers to [Genesis 1:2](https://biblehub.com/genesis/1-2.htm), “Now the earth was formless and empty, darkness was over the surface of the deep, and the Spirit of God was hovering over the waters” where the word translated by the NIV as “Spirit” is πνεῦμα (*pneuma*) in the Septuagint, meaning “breath”.

> [Bacon] then he breathed light into the face of man

This refers to [Genesis 2:7](https://biblehub.com/genesis/2-7.htm), “Then the LORD God formed a man from the dust of the ground and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life, and the man became a living being.” Bacon strengthens the parallelism with Genesis 1:2 by using “face” in both cases.

> [Bacon] and still he breatheth and inspireth light into the face of his chosen.

Here the sense of “light” is:

> **light, *n.* 8.a.i.** With spiritual reference: the brightness of heaven, the illumination of the soul by divine truth or love, etc.
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Two forms of light are being discussed in your Bacon quote.

the light of sense: light perceived by the eye; the light of reason: light of understanding, of knowledge,even of metaphysical truths, of the spirit.

https://www.shakespeareswords.com/Public/Glossary.aspx?Id=15734

I've been asked to provide more context.  In western  philosophical tradition, reason was a divine gift that allows humankind to perceive Truth. In the Bacon quote  God "breathes" the light of reason into the face of man. The Latin word for spirit, *spiritus*, is related to the word for breathe, *spirare*.

Comment: Is this a quote? I feel like you need some more context

Comment: No, that is not a quote.  I'm not going to get into the biblical, just gloss what was meant by light of sense and light of reason. It's a commonplace notion, what more context is required except to gloss "sense"?

Comment: It would be good to introduce it, like "X is defined as A. On the other hand, Y deals with B". It's hard to read right now

Comment: It's not a definition, but a *gloss* of the particular meaning of the word used in the passage.